# Scope confusion and modification for dictionary - want to confirm why my code works

Tags: python, dictionary, scope, reference

I am required to write a function that inverts a dictionary (which I have correctly :) ). A return statement is not permitted, meaning that as I understand it, the original dictionary must be amended. Given that the dictionary is passed as an argument to the function this means that we have a reference to it, allowing for it to be directly modified eliminating the need for a return statement/value.

1st try:

```
def invert (dictionary: dict):
dictionary = {value : key for key, value in dict.items(dictionary)}
print(dictionary)

if __name__ == "__main__":
s = {1: 100, 2 : 200}
#print(s)
invert(s)
print(s)
```

This did not work, I think because I have not modified the original dictionary, rather,dictionary now points to the new object in the function, not the original which won't be accessible from within the function now. H
**However, this is only within the function. The original dictionary is unchanged, because it is a global scope variable that has modified in a local scope context, the function (is this correct?)**

I tried making a new object, performing the inversion process, and then updating the original  as below:

```
def invert (dictionary: dict):
    inverted_dictionary={}
    inverted_dictionary = {value : key for key, value in dictionary.items()}
    print(inverted_dictionary)
 dictionary = inverted_dictionary
    print(dictionary)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    s = {1: 10, 2 : 20, 3: 30}
    invert(s)
    print(s)
```

**The inversion occurs in the function yes, and when I return inverted_dictionary, there is confirmation that the inversion has taken place. The copying occurs correctly in the function because of local scope, and because I have again, created a new object with the "=".**

I got the code to work as I wanted it to, as follows:

```
def invert (dictionary: dict):
inverted_dictionary={}
inverted_dictionary = {value : key for key, value in dictionary.items()}
dictionary.clear()
dictionary.update(inverted_dictionary)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    s = {1: 10, 2 : 20, 3: 30}
    invert(s)
    print(s)
```

**I used clear() method to first remove all previous values within the dictionary, then the values of the inverted_dictionary variable were added to the original reference of the object, not a new reference of the object. (Is this correct?)**

Comment: as an aside, don't do this: `dict.items(dictionary)` just do `dictionary.items()` Edit: I see you do that later on 

Comment: dictionary.items() method accepts no parameters, is that the basis for your comment?

Comment: I meant you can just call the method directly on the instance (which in first example is a var named `dictionary`), you don't have to call the class method (i.e. Python built-in `dict`) passing the instance as arg

Comment: Ah! I didn't know that :) Thank you! Am I correct in my assumption that .items() doesn't take parameters?

Comment: correct, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

Comment: My approach to your actual question would be: don't bother trying to invert the dictionary "in place" (i.e. modifying the original instance) but just return the new inverted dict from `invert` and assign it back to your var like `s = invert(s)`